# Visual Basic Divide Double Randomly based on Divisor

Tags: vb.net, random, division

Ok, so I want to divide a number randomly not evenly... 
so lets say we have 20 I need 5 (Divisor) random chunks of 20.

> 4 4 4 4 4

Instead I want something like

> 6 2 4 3 5

It cant exceed the starting number

How can this be accomplished in vb?

Please help, Been stuck for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Iterator Function DivideUp(ByVal Number As Integer, ByVal Groups As Integer, Optional ByVal Variance As Integer = 5) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    Dim rnd As New Random()

    While Groups > 0 AndAlso Number > 0 
       If Groups = 1 Then
           Yield Number
           Exit Function
       End If
       If Variance > Number - Groups Then Variance = Number - Groups

       Dim temp As Integer = Number / Groups
       temp += rnd.Next(Variance * -1, Variance)

       Yield temp
       Number -= temp
       Groups -= 1
    End While
End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
For Each num As Integer In DivideUp(20, 5)
    Console.WriteLine(num)
Next
```

Something more conventional:

```
Public Function DivideUp(ByVal Number As Integer, ByVal Groups As Integer, Optional ByVal Variance As Integer = 5) As Integer()
    Static rnd As New Random()

    Dim result(Groups-1) As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To Groups - 1
       If Variance > Number - Groups Then Variance = Number - Groups
       If i = Groups - 1 Then
           result(i) = Number
       Else
           Dim temp As Integer = Number / Groups
           temp += rnd.Next(Variance * -1, Variance)
           result(i) = temp
           Number -= temp
       End If
    Next i
    Return result
End Function
```

If you want to get real fancy, you could use a log or natural log of your random variance to try make it more likely to stay closer to the median, ie: if your number divides evenly into groups of 4, do you want it to be rarer to see a 2 than a 3, rarer to see a 1 than a 2?

Finally, a test harness:

```
Dim errorCount As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To 10000
    Dim items = DivideUp(100, 12)
    Dim sum As Integer = 0 
    For Each j As Integer In items
        Console.Write(j)
        Console.Write(" ")
        sum += j
    Next j   
    Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", sum)
    If sum <> 100 Then
        errorCount += 1
        Dim tempColor = Console.ForegroundColor
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
        Console.WriteLine("Error: incorrect total!")
        Console.ForegroundColor = tempColor
    End If     
Next i
If errorCount > 0 Then
    Dim tempColor = Console.ForegroundColor
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
    Console.WriteLine("Error: incorrect total on {0} tries!")
    Console.ForegroundColor = tempColor
End If
```

If you're working with real money, you need to use a cryptographic random number generator (the simple `Random` type won't cut it) and you want to actually save each of these results (plus run it more like a few million times than just 10,000). Then you pull that data into something like R and graph your distributions, to make sure things flat (evenly distributed) with no visible bias. And you have to do this for a number of different Number/Group/Variance combinations. Failure to rigorously validate the randomness the purge any bias **will** result in someone gaming your system to win much more often than they should.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want the distribution of values to look like. What are the constraints? Like, do you want them all to be roughly equal, like each one around 1/5 of the total with some variation? Or is it acceptable and/or desirable for, say, the first bucket to have about half, the second about half of the remainder, etc? Does it have to be possible for any bucket to have any number between 0 and 20? Or is 0 an unacceptable value? Etc.

Given all that, my first thought of a solution is:

```
function deal(total as integer, bucket_count as integer) as buckets() as integer
  dim r as new random()
  dim buckets(bucket_count-1) as integer
  for bx=0 to bucket_count-2
    buckets(bx)=r.next(total*2/(bucket_count-bx))
    total-=buckets(bx)
  next
  buckets(bucket_count-1)=total
  return buckets
end function
```

I haven't tested this code so excuse me if there are bugs, but the basic idea is:

We want each bucket to get about 1/5 of the total. So I assign the first bucket a random number between 0 and 2/5. Then I subtract this number from the running total, and I assign the second bucket a random number between 0 and 2/4 of what's left, then the third bucket a random number between 0 and 2/3 of what's left after that, the fourth bucket a random number between 0 and 2/2 (i.e. all) of what's left, and then put whatever's left in the fifth bucket.

Whether that's the sort of distribution you want, I don't know. It looks like it should give plausible distributions.

Comment: And the big question... is this for something that involves real money, where we need to use cryptographic random and validate the distribution at each level?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Well, yes, good point. If this is, "I want to generate some random numbers for a software test and I need some variety to make sure it doesn't work only in the very simple case", then some quick throw-together code like this should be fine. If this relates to awarding prizes in a million-dollar lottery, then you need requirements to be strictly defined.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I once worked for a company that had a client that asked us to build a web site for them to collect entries for a contest they were running where the prize was a free trip for 4 with hotel, air fare, rental car, and entertainment, surely worth many thousands of dollars. Then at the end of the contest they asked us to select which entry was the winner, with no criteria for how we should select the winner. I thought, wow, is it too late for me to enter?